# Rails 5.0 to 5.2: how to migrate schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ruby-on-rails-5.2

After updating my gems, I'm not being able to run `rails db:schema:load`. The error reported is:

```
ActiveRecord::MismatchedForeignKey: Column `user_id` on table 
`user_applications` has a type of `int(11)`.
This does not match column `id` on `users`, which has type 
`bigint(20)`.
```

This has to do with some default int type for primary key change from rails 5.2 (or rails 5.1, I don't know). My question is: how should I "migrate" the db/schema? Or, can I set the primary key to be 32bit integer? Because I already tried in `application.rb`:

```
config.generators do |generator|
  generator.orm :active_record, primary_key_type: :integer
end
```

but it didn't do anything when running the aforementioned task.

Answer (score 0):

Move your old scheme file and create a new one:

```
$ rails db:schema:dump
```

Comment: Thx! It sorta works, but some weird things happen: The `:limit` field from text columns gets erased, `using: :btree` also gets removed (I guess that is by design),   and foreign key declarations (`add_foreign_key` calls) just vanish, is this expected?

Comment: Hard to know, can we see your migration file?

Comment: I don't think this has to do with the migration file (I want to migrate only the schema.rb). But `add_foreign_key` calls disappearing is indeed strange.